# Whether to use Const parameter in the declaration of a function

Tags: c++

I am studying on Essential C++ by lippman. Here is the source code I am confused with.

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <vector>
#include <list>

template <const typename elemtype>
inline elemtype* begin(const vector<elemtype> &vec) {
    return vec.empty() ? 0 : &vec[0];
}

template <const typename elemtype>
inline elemtype* end(const vector<elemtype> &vec) {
    return vec.empty() ? 0 : &vec[vec.size()];
}

template < typename elemtype>
int* find(const elemtype *first, const elemtype *last, elemtype value) {
    if (!first || !last) {
        return 0;
    }
for (; first != last; ++first) {
    if (*first == value)
        return first;
}
return 0;
}

int main()
{
    int a[] = { 1,1,2,3,5,8,13,21,34 };
    int search_value = 5;
    int *pi = find(a, a + 9, search_value);
    vector<int> svec(a, a + 9);
    int *srch_add;
    srch_add = find(begin(svec), end(svec), search_value);
    cout << *srch_add;
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

This example from essential c++ actually come out with an error on the call of the second find function in main. After carefully checking with all possible way that error may comes from, I finally found that the mistake lies within the const parameter of the inline functions-begin and end. They should be modified like this:

```
template <typename elemtype>
inline elemtype* begin(vector<elemtype> &vec) {
    return vec.empty() ? 0 : &vec[0];
}

template <typename elemtype>
inline elemtype* end(vector<elemtype> &vec) {
    return vec.empty() ? 0 : &vec[vec.size()];
}
```

I solved the problem while not understanding why should I do this. The inline function returns the address of the first integer and the next integer after the vector. After the inline functions are executed, the &vec has gone, and the pointer in the find function should be able to change the address pointed to. Why there is a discontinuity here?

Comment: FYI, the standard convention is to use `T` as the typename template parameter.

Comment: Did you try, keeping const keyword on parameters and also putting const to return values as well? It seems to me that you're returning the parameter(first) from those inline functions in one o the cases but if you make parameters const and return value non-const that create inconsistency, that's why it works when you remove const on parameters, so it should work as well if you put const to return type in function signature and keep const keeywords on parameters as well

Comment: `template <const typename elemtype>` is not valid C++ and should not compile.

Comment: `vec[vec.size()]` exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: @OnurA. What I did is using constant parameter `vector<int>` and return the address of the first element `&vec[0]`. And then I assign this address to a constant pointer `const int* first` where the content of the pointer is a constant. Then I changed the address this pointer pointed to. Is there a problem within this operation?

Comment: @OnurA. Oops, I'm sorry I actually posted the right code into the first block. Would you please look again at my code so that you could know what my question is about.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Oops, I'm sorry I actually posted the right code into the first block. Would you please look again at my code so that you could know what my question is about. And the you can find the `size()` in the `<vector>`.

Comment: I'm not sure what it is you fixed and what I'm supposed to look at again. `template <const typename elemtype>` is still not valid C++ and still wouldn't compile; `vec[vec.size()]` is still a buffer overrun exhibiting undefined behavior.

Comment: In `begin()`, since `vec` is const, its contents are const too (cannot be modified), and so `&vec[0]` is of type `const elemtype*`. This pointer is therefore not implicitly convertible to `elemtype*` (if it were, it would allow you to modify contents of a supposedly const vector). Thus, you have a type mismatch between the declared return type of the function, and the type of the expression in `return` statement.

Comment: @JackieWang you should post code that actually compiles. Seems like this code is trying to implement the standard begin, end and find functions but using pointers instead of an iterator. To me it seems strange that your find function always returns int* even though its input type is templated. As far as the const goes you should let it be part of the templated type. Look to the standard library for examples of how this is done.

Comment: @JackieWang &vec[vec.size()] in the end() method, will make you a lot of headache and produce subtle problems :) make it &vec[vec.size()-1]